# How can I make an <li> change color when it's clicked and stay with that color until a redirect?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, menu, html-lists

How can I make an `<li>` in a navigation menu change color after clicking it and stay with that color as long as it's on that same page of my website, preferably without using JavaScript or jQuery? Thanks.

Example:
https://smartsoftcode.com/preview/kenox/demo/index-v2.html

Each item in the navigation menu at the top changes color when it's clicked and stays with that color until another list item is clicked.

Comment: There are a number of different ways you could approach this. Do you have anymore context on the website you are building and what you have tried so far?

Comment: @djnetherton I have the navigation menu done. Now i want the button/"LI" to stay yellow when i click on it, and stay yellow when i am in that page related to the button as you can see in the site example..

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one brother "active" method 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.active:active {
  color: red;
}
.focus:focus {
  color: red;
}
:target {
  color: red;
}
</style>
<body>
<a href='#target1' id='target1' class='target'>Target 1</a>
<a href='#target2' id='target2' class='target'>Target 2</a>
<a href='#target3' id='target3' class='target'>Target 3</a>

</body>
</html>
```